# Using a remote MySQL database for a WP install on localhost

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, localhost

I am trying to use a database on my SiteGround hosting account for a WP install on my localhost (where I have Apache, PHP running using DesktopServer).

I am using the IP given in Remote MySQL section of cPanel for DB_HOST. I have whitelisted my IP. Also double checked to ensure that DB_NAME, DB_USER and DB_PASSWORD are correct. Gave full permissions to the user to access that database.

When I visit the WP install page, http://local.dev/wp-admin/install.php it says "Error establishing a database connection".

I sent a support ticket to the host and they concluded that everything is fine from their end:

> I added a test IP of mine to cPanel > Remote MySQL and connected successfully to your database using the credentials shown on your screen shot...Everything seems properly and you should be able to connect remotely, so if you cannot connect your local app, I suppose that there is some local issue.

Can anyone give a clue as to how I can troubleshoot this?

I am using a Mac.

Comment: this might be helpful http://wordpress.org/support/topic/setting-up-wp-with-remote-database

Comment: Have you checked your `wp-config.php` file for the correct DB parameters? Also if you use CPanel, it is better to add an wild-card `%` character as allowed host, because most probably your IP will change over time.

Comment: user3587554: I went through that topic now and am not sure how to check the following:

"If you're using phpMyAdmin to manage your databases, all you have to do is click on the Privileges tab, and check the host column."

I do not find a Privileges tab in phpMyAdmin of the host.



bodi0: Yes, I did. I was planning to use the % character if it works once in the first place without it. I double checked the db connection strings and my IP and they are fine.